# GridControl detail grid

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, gridcontrol

I must do something like that;

I have 2 sql tables like this

Results:

[image: Results]

ResultType:

[image: ResultTypes]

I wanna show Results on GridControl. If "Test" has more than 1 parameter, it will have detail grid. If not it will show the result on master grid. Like this:

[image: Grid]

when I click on "+" i wanna see the detail grid. How can I do it?
Thanks..

Note: I don't wanna use the DataSets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is shown in the [documentation here.](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument733)

Just modify the information to fit the method of grid population you want to use.

Comment: it's ASPxGridView. I'm working on windows forms. This is a web control.

Answer (score 0):

Create in your Results object a property List ResultTypes, DevExpress will do the mapping to show the details

Comment: And if you want to map your ResultTypes to a specific GridView, you must add GridControl1.LevelTree.Nodes.Add("PropertyName", GridView)